# compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ClientService: (?)

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, rest

I am a getting the following error on my console even when my paramters match the parameters in the database:- compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ClientService: (?).
client.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class Client {
 id: number;
 firstName: string;
 lastName: string;
 emailId: string;

 constructor()
 constructor(id?: number, firstname?: string, lastname?: string, email?: string) {
  this.id = id;
  this.firstName = firstname;
  this.lastName = lastname;
  this.emailId = email;
    }
  }

 export class ClientService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  saveClient(client: Client): Observable<Client> {
  return this.http.post<Client>('http://localhost:9091/clients', client); }}
```

ajout-clients.component.ts

```
import {Component, forwardRef, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Client, ClientService} from '../client.service';
@Component({
selector: 'app-ajout-client',
templateUrl: './ajout-client.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./ajout-client.component.css'] 
})
export class AjoutClientComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject(ClientService) private clientService:ClientService) 
{this.clientService=clientService; }
client: Client = new Client();
submitted = false;
ngOnInit() {
}
newClient(): void {
  this.submitted = false;
  this.client = new Client();
}
 save() {
    this.clientService.saveClient(this.client)
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data), error => console.log(error));
    this.client = new Client();
   }
}
```

the ajout-client.component.html

```
<h3>Create Client</h3>
<div [hidden]="submitted" style="width: 400px;">
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 <div class="form-group">
      <label >First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" required [(ngModel)]="client.firstName" 
    name="firstName">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" required [(ngModel)]="client.lastName" 
    name="lastName">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailId" required [(ngModel)]="client.emailId" 
    name="emailId">
    </div>

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
 </form>
   </div>

     <div [hidden]="!submitted">
     <h4>You submitted successfully!</h4>
     <!-- <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="newEmployee()">Add</button> -->
     </div>
```

i keep getting that error i dont know why  , any help please

Comment: Did you import HttpClientModule in the module where ClientService is declared?

Comment: @David , yes i did but i figured out that the problem is that i added the annotation Injectable to the Client class instead of the ClientService but i really appreciate your help ,thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `@Injectable` to your `ClientService` not to your `Client` class:

```
@Injectable()
export class ClientService {}
```

Otherwise dependency injection does not work